# magento1.9 sms for customer when order placed

Tags: orders, messages, magento1.9.3

Is there any sms extension available for free to send transaction sms like order confirmation or any less amount of extension suggest me. Am using magento 1.9.3

Comment: There are so many, depending on the different functionalities, one of the most popular we could find is, https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-sms-sms-notification-sms-marketing-1.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/msg91-sms-extension.html

please try these free extensions